# Dual-booting Windows 98 on an iMac G3

Tags: mac-os-classic, windows-98, imac, imac-g3

Is it possible to dual boot Windows 98 or Windows 95 on an iMac G3 running Mac OS 9.2?

Comment: This will be quite slow.

Answer (score 9):

Windows 95 and 98 require an x86-type CPU (and more generally, a PC, with BIOS, etc.), so they can't run on PowerPC G3-based computers without an emulation layer of some sort.

Answer (score 6):

Not dual-boot, but you could track down an old copy of Virtual PC for the Mac by Microsoft. VPC was an x86 emulator for the Mac OS X PowerPC line of computers and supported Windows 98 out of the box. I can't recall if it supported '95 as well since it has been several years since I've used it, but I know that it did work reasonably well with '98.

Now as far as how *fast* it would run that Windows 98 installation ... I don't know about that on a G3. It worked reasonably well on a 1.8GHz G5 and 1.2GHz G4, so I can't speak to a ??? MHz G3.

Comment: I did use [Connectix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectix) [Virtual PC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Virtual_PC#Virtual_PC_by_Connectix) to run Windows 95/98 on a G3, slow but usable. The G4/G5 could even run Win 2k/XP in a somewhat usable way if you stripped down the systems. Connectix also released [Virtual Game Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectix_Virtual_Game_Station) which runs PlayStation games on the G3 at full speed.